# Removing one applications removes even more

Tags: apt, package-management, firefox, wine, dpkg

The problem has occurred even before but it wasn't any special case like this one. It all started when I tried to install `wine` in my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I did a simple `sudo install wine` and I hit enter.
I saw it was being downloaded from the repositories and while I was doing other thing on google and something happened. Firefox just was removed from my `favorites` and google icon disappeared.

I went staring at terminal and I was seeing that Ubuntu was removing a lot of packages like following: openjdk, firefox, google, files, settings, kerneloops and many more. The worst part is that I can't download them again because I will get a dependency error which I'm unable to fix.

The fun thing is that when I was trying to remove one application by using command (it was a dependency version problem): `sudo apt remove --purge <package name>` it said me that more applications would get removed.

Please Help Me. I don't know what to do and why this happens. If you leave a message would be great.

Comment: It only does it if you give it permission, ie. the `sudo install wine` will give a list of what it requires to install the packages and asks for confirmation (unless you gave it beforehand with -y).   If you used unofficial Ubuntu repositories, which from your description you must have, it may have required many Ubuntu software to be removed to satisfy requirements of the unofficial source. You can enter `apt-cache policy wine` to see where you grabbed it from, as you've likely added a source that you possibly shouldn't have added OR not have given permission to remove those packages

Comment: Show us the complete terminal session in your question (stored in /var/log/apt/term.log).

Comment: @user535733 https://pastebin.com/unZEPArP < here. I edited the "Removing" to the "FIXED" to applications I successfully installed again

Comment: @guiverc idk where it got it from since I checked the sources.list file and it was fine, it was from legit source. What is strange is the second thing that when I try to remove a package it removes even more....

Comment: When you originally installed Ubuntu, did you originally install a different flavor? Or from the minimal (netinstall) .iso? Those are the two usual causes of `ubuntu-desktop` removal causing a mass removal. Reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`, and most of those packages will return with it. Advice: ALWAYS read your apt output, which is there precisely to prevent this kind of situation..

Comment: @user535733 I can't install `ubuntu-desktop` as it gives me an error. It was the first package I tried to install again. I think I did take the full .iso, I don't remember but I think netinstall wasn't the one.

Comment: Show us complete input and output that includes the error. "an error" is too vague to work with.

Comment: @user535733 here > ```sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Looks like you have a sources problem (expected that). Next, show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: here > https://pastebin.com/qeN8yFPq

Comment: This looks like a Debian Jessie system, not Ubuntu at all. You have Debian sources, not Ubuntu sources. That's why you cannot find `ubuntu-desktop` -- it's not in Debian. I don't know how you installed `ubuntu-desktop`, but mixing Debian and Ubuntu packages is Not Wise. It creates a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) with version conflicts and ends in tears.

Comment: Looks to me like you have three options: 1) Run an `apt dist-upgrade` and hope apt can work the dependencies out. 2) Remove those PPAs  and uninstall the packages they provided to get you back to stock Debian Jessie. 3) Clean-install Debian or Ubuntu. Debian is Off Topic for this site, sorry.

Comment: IIRC i took iso from this site: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop . and I never messed up with sources list file. Though I may ask a friend for its Ubuntu repo since we live in the same country before I go at clean install. Thank you for all your comments. Though I'm still curios why wine needed to remove applications tho.....

Comment: When you add packages for a 2018 release of Ubuntu, many packages were updated. On removal of later packages, the 'newer' packages likely also needed to be removed following dependency rules each package has - ie. your system became the *FrankenDebian* referred to by user535733.  Debian jessie(8) is from 2015 and so just by time it's dependencies won't align; let alone Ubuntu commonly having newer packages included anyway (most of my current 20.04 box still has newer packages than my debian bullseye(11-*testing*) box. Compare https://packages.debian.org/ with https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @guiverc I understand but in fact I don't know how old are the packages I install because everything happens in the background. In fact I have noticed a change tho. When I used to `apt update` in some lines it used to show me like this: `http:country.archive`(and it continued) but now I'm strangely not seeing it. Since you said to not include the debian repo in `sources.list` file, should I replace it with the repos in `sources.list.backup`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I fixed it by myself but a lot of credit goes to: @user535733 and @guiverc.

**What Symptoms You Had?**

After trying to install `wine` the package removed a plenty more applications and I wasn't able to install them back because I had the `couldn't fin the package` because I had a debian repo in my `sources.list` file. One of main packages was `ubuntu-desktop` which it failed to install and after removing it, I was only with text interface and this led me to not see graphics.

**What steps did you reproduce to solve the problem?**

Well basically after running some commands to understand the problem and me and @user535733 found that I had the a `debian jessie` repo and this didn't let me to install the `ubuntu-dekstop` package and created the `FrankenDebian`. While talking with @guiverc it made me remember how `sudo apt update` looked in the past and I went on the `/etc/apt/` folder and replaced the debian repo with official ubuntu repositories.

Note that this solution is for people who had problems from debian repository. Check your `sources.list` file and it should look like this:
`deb http://yourcountry.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted`

Thanks All :D